# Alternative for document.execCommand("insertText", false, text)

Tags: javascript, dom, textarea, undo-redo, execcommand

I am using `document.execCommand("insertText", false, /* some text */)` in a **textarea to replace text while allowing Ctrl+Z undo to work**; this is supported in every browser I have tested but I know this is deprecated. What is/Is there a better working alternative for this specific case?

Other StackOverflow answers have given alternatives but mostly focus on contenteditable elements and copy/paste, which is irrelevant here.

I also don't feel very comfortable making my own undo/redo stack as it would increase complexity too much. However, if it's the only feasible solution I'm fine doing it.

Comment: Sadly the deprecation of `document.execcomand` is a result of browser vendors  implementing details of it according to their whim, instead of negotiating a common cooperative standard. Think "browser wars". As a consequent,  the `insertText` method is not protected by standards. Lobby your browser vendor to support `insertText` in  an ongoing standard that can be expanded with agreed upon methods in the future, without requiring user permission to provide text editing in HTML.

Comment: Personally I am using `execcommand.insertText` in a current project, in the hope that removing support for this particular method will be treated akin to "breaking the web".

Comment: @traktor - yes, staying with it does seem like the best option for me. I have had other problems with Chromium and Firefox treating browser functionality different.